# Make all dom elements movable

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-ui-draggable

I know I can do something like:

```
  $(function() {
    $( ".className" ).draggable();
  });
```

If I want to make the class `className` draggable, but how about making all elements inside the page draggable ?

Comment: Yowza. Trying to lock up the user's browser? :-)

Comment: I'm dying to know why you want this!

Comment: Hopefully, this would be just hypothetical, not real world, right? Like adding `*, *:before, *:after { transition: all 1s ease; }` to your CSS.

Comment: If you know the elements you could make it slightly less taxing, ie if you are only using divs, p, h1, span, etc. And there could be lots of elements you don't need to target, especially inline elements, so these would not be selected by the * wildcard.

Answer (score 3):

Against all good sense you could do this:

```
$('body *').draggable();
```

Note that it's likely to severely tax most systems, though.

Answer (score 2):

`$( "*" ).draggable();` Should do what you are asking

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    $('*').draggable();
});
```

P.S. DO NOT DO THIS... it will really slow down your browser.